# Start with MonetDB development

Tags: development-environment, monetdb

I want to integrate features into MonetDB, more specifically into the dictionary part of it. I found some information [here](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Guide/Compression), but this is not really elaborate.

The concrete feature I want to integrate is secondary in my question here. My biggest hurdle at the moment is: how do I start to develop MonetDB?

I was able to download the source and build it as described [here](https://www.monetdb.org/Developers/SourceCompile). But where to go from there?

My preferred way would be: get MonetDB in some form of an IDE, set various breakpoints, send a SQL query and explore the code from there.

Is this possible? What development environment do you use? Is gdb debugging the only possibility? How do you debug?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I figured it out myself. Maybe, somebody else will face this problem, wherefore I answer my own question. I finally ended up with Eclipse and describe a possible way to start MonetDB development/debugging:

- Clone MonetDB repository from the official repository, e.g., [from Github](https://github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB)
- Download the C++ version of a [current Eclipse release](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/)
- In Eclipse click on `File` > `New` > `C/C++` > `Makefile Project with Existing Code` > `Next`. Insert the cloned repository dictionary as `Existing Code Location` and select the `GNU Autotools Toolchain`
- Now you should be able to build MonetDB inside of Eclipse
- After a successful build, you can choose `Binaries` from the Project Explorer. There you can right click the different binaries and use to `run as` or `debug as`

This finishes the setup of MonetDB inside Eclipse. Now, it depends on what you want to debug. If you want to change something at the server, you might want to debug `monetdbd`. My tips to do this are:

- Start debugging of `monetdbd` per right click as explained before
- Close the debug session and adjust the debug configuration
- On the `Arguments` tab, insert the arguments: `start -n <path to your dbfarm>`. This will keep the database daemon from going into the background
- On the `Debugger` tab, select `Automatically debug forked process` and optionally `Non-stop mode`
- A new debug session will now automatically stop at the main of `monetdbd` and will also show the threads of the forked `mserver5` process